# Damage hole in seat tube after sandblasting, is it possible?

Tags: steel

I had this 29er steel 853 Reynolds frame, with the paint in very bad state, no rust or corrosion,
so I decided to have it sandblasted and repainted,...
The result I think that it is that I got it damaged with a hole in seat tube, just over the housing stop, after sandblasting, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Is it a fairly neat hole? Could be a vent hole that was formerly closed with brass or silver, which can easily be worn off in blasting.

Comment: it sounds possible and interesting,
yes, it is quite neat, and very small. and inside the re is no rust, so I would imagine you could be right.
I will of course use it, as it is.

Comment: Drill the hole 1-2mm bigger (do it in stages, clear the paint first, then if its not obviously a drilled hole, take it out a bit further). Check the thickness of the frame material. It could be rusted internally, although being a 29er its less than 7 years old, with no external rust, internal rust is unlikely.  I would be temped to poke around with an endoscope unless i was certain it was a purpose drilled hole.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take it to a frame builder locally so that he can have a look. Very interesting inputs.

Comment: A venthole from brazing that was probably covered by the previous paint. Just leave it alone. It will keep the inside of the tube from rusting through air exchange. Take it as an opportunity to spray penetrating oil inside..

Comment: Answers to this question can only be wild guesses and speculation without more information and better quality pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The picture lacks the resolution needed. Rust can creep under paint from a small chip, and in that spot(behind the seat tube you say?) it would get a large amount of water and slop. As for the shop, a bad operator with the wrong blasting abrasive can easily erode a hole like this, with a reasonable operator it is not likely, even a brass plug should be safe unless it was soldered improperly and basically fell out.

Do not leave it open or it will collect splashes, condensation, and then rust inside. A spot of siloxane/silicone caulk or gasket maker will suffice, get clear or try to match the color a bit. Another option is a smooth/round headed sheet metal screw of the right diameter, "thread cutting" type.(fine thread not the coarse "self tapping" sort)
 Be sure to dope the threads with some low strength loc-tight, grease, or gasket maker(only one, not all three) so it doesn't rust in place or rattle out.

Comment: Hi Max, I believe that the picture has the right resolution. Then, of course it wss powder coated so the edges of the holes are not o visible.. I have closed the tiny hole with some paste made for this purposes. I then got the RAL code for the colour and matched the original one. Not worried about tubes strenght and definitely not corrosion. If it was corrosion it would have damaged other areas like the BB before. Now it looks good and I have been riding for 1 year, so all good.

Comment: It is good you fixed it, if the question is answered you should mark it as answered.
 The resolution of the picture is good for showing the location of the hole but it is too low to see the details of the hole when zoomed in.

Comment: Unless you can answer or add to the discussion there is no point in writing here.  you should anyway read other people's answers before writing. The point is how a hole like this was possible, you suggest how to cover it which is not the point. I am sure that somebody could know how the hole happened to be there. See comment sbout breathing hole from when welded....

Comment: With the poor picture and coating of new paint no one can diagnose how the hole was formed, only guessing is possible. My answer did offer a possibility for how it was formed. I disagree with the breathing hole for welding answer because the top end of that tube is fully open for the seat.

Comment: Not really a place where water collects and it could open a rust hole. The picture is good, and yes the coating covers the margins.

Answer (score -2):

No *visible* rust. Sand blast only has the power to blow out rust.

And I would have gone for powder coating.

What would they have in the shop to punch a hole like that and not leave a dent?

Comment: there is no rust at all, checked inside with a light torch too.
I don't think they have punched it, 
...did you see the comment above from Nathan? what do you think?

Comment: Paint in very bad state and you are sure no rust.  Gone and never there are not the same.

Comment: paint in bad state I mean that Niner paint is quite famous for being quite thing and scratch easily. The paint was quite in a sad state, so I have decided to give it a new look. This might have been there before sandblasting, not sure...nobody really looks much behind the rear wheel....

Comment: Nobody looks behind the rear wheel?  This is going no where.  Sorry I could not be of more assistance.

Comment: I just meant that nobody noticed that before...so me and the previous owner never checked there...
sentences like "Gone and never there are not the same" are not much clear either, I think you are not being of much assistance anyway....